# Extending the Android application certificate past its expiration

Tags: android, certificate, google-play

Recently I saw this:
[image]

In the unlikelihood any of my apps survive (and I survive and everything else dependent survives) until 2037, will my apps have to be re-released with a new package name because of needing a new certificate?

Is there no way to extend a certificate?

Comment: -1 I think this should be asked in 20+ years time if we still have android and your app is still in use, for know and the immediate future why worry

Comment: Ha Ha Ha... I liked the topic :) But why do you want to extend the certificate ? I can bet, android will be dead before 2033.. :-)

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Sorry, Tom. Or moved to Android Enthusiast? @Anil I'm not wanting to, I'm asking if it's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot extend the validity of an existing certificate.

However, when first creating your certificate, set the validity to be as long as you think the product will survive. Look [here for instructions](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert) on how to accomplish this.

See the `-validity <days>` flag.